# How to print 10 numbers/phrases per line in a Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

After a for loop,
example: `for( int number = 1 ; number < 100 ; number++ )`

in which the multiples 3 print boo and multiples of 5 print casper and multiples of 3 and 5 print boocasper,and everything else as the original number. How would you write a code to print these values, 10 per line.

I figured out the coding to output the values of these multiples,I just need help figuring out printing ten of these values/phrases per line.

Comment: Print a line break after each number that is a multiple of 10?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post what you've got so far.

Comment: `int` is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
    document.write("boocasper ");
  } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
    document.write("boo ");
  } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
    document.write("casper ");
  }else{
    document.write(i+" ");
  }
  if (i % 10==0) {
    document.write("<br/>");
  }
}
```